# Javascript composition how to extend an object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, composition

I am trying to adopt the new ES6 feature to better compose objects without class inheritance. However, I don't understand how to extend and object or overwrite a function. The code below uses the composition pattern with Object.assign().

**Question**: How can I create a second object factory UnderlinedCell without copying the whole TextCell object. It behaves like TextCell with the small difference that getHeight returns getHeight + 1 and the draw method adds a line with dashes "-".

**Why I want to do this?**: I am trying to get my head around the composition concept as explained here in this video [Composition over Inheritance from Johansson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA)

Here is the code for the object factory TextCell.

```js
const getHeight = (state) => ({
  getHeight: () => state.text.length
})

const draw = (state) => ({
  draw: () => state.text.join(" | ")
})

const TextCell = (text) => {
  let state = {
    text: text.split("\n")
  }

  return Object.assign(getHeight(state), draw(state))
}

console.log("The height of the cell is %s", TextCell("foo\nbar").getHeight())
console.log(TextCell("foo\nbar").draw())
```

Comment: Why don't use classes?

Comment: And what is the reason that you don't want to write it that way: [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jt0y3eLr/1/)

Comment: To answer above questions I added the "why" section in the post.

Comment: MPJ got composition completely wrong, and actual composition never once made an appearance in his video. What he actually described, without realizing it, is multiple inheritance. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5dxq6i/composition_over_inheritance/da8bplv/

Comment: Hi Jeff, I realized, when testing the example solutions here in the post, that I ended up with simple inheritance. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, `state` is private. This means we can only do with exposed public methods of `TextCell` i.e. `getHeight` and `draw`.

Now, `UnderlineCell` is a function that composes over `TextCell` and *extends* the implementation for `TextCell`. *e.g.*

```js
const getHeight = (state) => ({
  getHeight: () => state.text.length
})

const draw = (state) => ({
  draw: () => state.text.join(" | ")
})

const TextCell = (text) => {
  const state = {
    text: text.split("\n")
  }

  return Object.assign(getHeight(state), draw(state))
}


const UnderlineCell = (text) => {
  const textCell = TextCell(text);
  const getHeight = () => textCell.getHeight() + 1;
  const line = '\n------\n';
  const draw = () => textCell.draw().replace(' | ', line) + line;

  return {...textCell, getHeight, draw}; 
}

const uCell = UnderlineCell('hello\nthis');
console.log(uCell.draw());
```

Comment: Wow, so you are using the brand new object merging spread syntax. I had to look it up to understand why this works. Stackoverflow is just the coolest place on earth. Thank you Oluwafemi!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why the complexity of a closure is used in the given code instead of using the regular `this`, because this would also perfectly fine, moreover the given code does not look that maintainable, and the worst of all it hides the original `state` object which prevent of extending the object later. You could rewrite it like that and achieve what you are asking:

```
const getHeight = () => ({
  getHeight() {
    return this.text.length
  }
})

const draw = () => ({
  draw() {
    return this.text.join(" | ")
  }
})

const TextCell = (text) => {
  let state = {
    text: text.split("\n")
  }

  return Object.assign(state, getHeight(), draw())
}

const TextCell2 = (text) => {
  let state = TextCell(text)

  var originalGetHeight = state.getHeight;

  return Object.assign(state, {
    getHeight() {
      // use the original original getHeight and append + 1
      return originalGetHeight.call(this) + '1'
    },
    draw() {
      return this.text.join(" - ")
    }
  });
}

console.log("The height of the cell is %s", TextCell("foo\nbar").getHeight())
console.log(TextCell("foo\nbar").draw())

console.log("The height of the cell is %s", TextCell2("foo\nbar").getHeight())
console.log(TextCell2("foo\nbar").draw())
```

But if you want to stay with the approach of hiding the `state` object, then you need to duplicate the code in `TextCell` because the `state` object created within the factory method is only accessible there and in the closures created by `getHeight(state)` and `draw(state)`.

Comment: I learn a lot from both solutions and both are right for my purpose. I will mark the first one as the solution, just because I can only select one answer. Thank you very much for providing me this answer. I am deeply grateful! One small remark, I changed  + '1' into +1 to not cause type casting.